# How to test 12 words passphrase for a Bitcoin address?

Tags: passphrase

I read same passphrase can be used on more wallet. How can I check passphrase goes with address without sending money, without the risk someone observe the passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

By passphrase I assume you mean the mnemonic.

If your wallet software supports creating multiple wallets, you can just make another wallet and just use the same mnemonic. Instead of creating a new wallet, you restore a wallet from the seed. To your software, it will be another wallet because it is stored in a different file.

Or you can download another wallet software and restore your mnemonic to a wallet with that other software. Note that that wallet must support using a mnemonic and uses the same format. Most wallets use BIP 39 mnemonics, however Electrum does not so you cannot restore an Electrum mnemonic to another wallet.

You should see the same addresses either way.

Answer (score 0):

You could download and run this [github repo](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39) on an offline machine. It's a tool that lets you work with and test bip39 mnemonics, the author of this repo also has an online demo https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ you can play with, but again it's better to save the website and run it offline.

Comment: Thanks and how to test? Fill 12 word in, then down at the bottom I will see lots of addresses and I will need to check my address is among them?

Comment: For me it seems Copay use `bip44`, and might used when mnemonics was created.